# When coding for Unix/Linux is it convention to use a trailing slash on path names, or to omit it?

Tags: shell-script, directory, variable

When programming for Unix/Linux, is it best practice to use a trailing slash, or to omit it?

For example:

**Trailing slash**

```
baseDir="/path/to/dir/"

#code#

outPath=${baseDir}addition/to/path/
```

**No Trailing Slash**

```
baseDir="/path/to/dir"

#code#

outPath=${baseDir}/addition/to/path

#or:
outPath=$baseDir/addition/to/path
```

I know that technically using the trailing slash explicitly indicates the path refers to a directory, but I also know that in practice it rarely matters (and is often omitted when working at the command line).  I also like that omitting the trailing slash makes it more explicit when I am appending to the path in a script.

Despite all this, I want to know if there is an explicit convention most people would expect my code to follow, or if this is a matter of personal taste.

Comment: I've never seen an explicit convention, and some applications (`rsync`) to different things with and without a trailing slash. In shell scripts I find it *convenient* to write `$baseDir/addition` instead of `${baseDir}addition`, but that's just my personal preference. Also notes double slashes in paths `path/todir//more/path/items` are often interpreted correctly.

Comment: Note that double slashes at the _root_ of a path can be [interpreted in an implementation dependent manner](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11).

Comment: This is down to the individual programmer's preferences (or to the preferences of their team). I closed this as a dupe of the question that muru suggested rather as "opinion-based" as referring to the dupe would be more constructive.